# PowerQuery code not working when trying to get Vlookup result between two tables

Tags: join, powerquery, vlookup, powerbi-desktop

I am working in Powerbi and in powerquery I'm trying to do equivalent formula as Vlookup in Excel.

Now I have several tables but have focused on the first to try and get it to work.

[Table OLRR and OLMPDirekta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUY13.png)

The wanted column and result that I want get in OLRR
[Table OLMPDirekta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo6Td.png)

The code I wrote with help of GTP for the new custom column in OLRR

`if [CostType] = "Absorption (DL)" then let matchingRow = Table.SelectRows(OLMPDirekta, each [Date] = [Date] and [CostCenter] = [CostCenter]), result = if Table.RowCount(matchingRow) > 0 then matchingRow{0}[DiffNyOLMPDirekta] else null in result else null`

[The code in custom column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thURd.png)

The result I get

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8LhR.png)

As you can see I get 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2 but would like it to be 2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1 depending on what the value for the corresponding costcenter and date (month) it is in OLMPDirekta

Any ideas on how to do this.
I don't think merge is right way to go for me.. Because depending on CostType I need to do this in another table and so on.

Thanks for all help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
x = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows","MPResultat",(x)=>if x[CostType] = "Absorption (DL)" then try Table.SelectRows(OLMPDirekta, each x[Date] = [Date] and x[CostCenter] = [CostCenter]){0}[DiffNyOLMPDirekta] otherwise null  else null )
in x
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer!

I tried to put in the code but I am doing it wrong somehow it seems. 

When I open the custom column and try to paste in your code 

x = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded BOTabeller","MPResultat",(x)=>if x[CostType] = "Absorption (DL)" then try Table.SelectRows(OLMPDirekta, each x[Date] = [Date] and x[CostCenter] = [CostCenter]){0}[DiffNyOLMPDirekta] otherwise null  else null )

I get an error:

Expression.Error: The name 'x' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's spelled correctly.

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Tried to do it but as you can understand I am utterly newbeginner to this. 
When I open the advanced editor the code looks like this

let
    Source = BuRR,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source, {"MainKey"}, BOTabeller, {"MainKey"}, "BOTabeller", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded BOTabeller" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "BOTabeller", {"OLUppdelning"}, {"OLUppdelning"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded BOTabeller", {"OLUppdelning", "Date", "CostCenter", "OrgLvl"}, {{"Total", each List.Sum([Value]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

Comment: Replace in #"Grouped Rows" with a comma.  Paste in above two line code after the comma